# Adding a Navigation to a View Controller with a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to add (or have) a navigation bar (or items) on the top of a View controller and and a tableview right below the navigation bar. The problem I'm having is when I set the tableview's datasource to View Controller, my app will crash (setting the tableview's delegate to View controller doesn't). For now, the code for the tableview are in the default ViewController.m. Do I have the tableview's code in the right place or did I connect something improperly?

Here's the error that it gives me:

> 2013-10-10 15:14:48.442 SomeApp[15058:a0b] -[UIViewController >tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d42450
>   2013-10-10 15:14:48.450 SomeApp[15058:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception >'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController >tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d42450'

[image: Current setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your view controller adheres to the proper protocols:

```
CustomViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

And add the necessary methods from these protocols to your implementation. These are the documentation links for your ease:

[UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I've added that to the ViewController.h as `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>' but it still crashed. I wonder if I placed the code that implements the tableview in the wrong place or if I need to create another view controller class for the ViewController that contains the tableview.

Comment: Have you implemented each of the protocol's required methods? If so, try deleting the file altogether. Then, create a new file, but when the prompt asks for the superclass, give it UITableViewController rather than UIViewController.

Comment: I got it working. I created a new class as you mentioned. I also had to change the Tableview's property to use the custom class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some methods that are required for your tableview to work,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

More information on [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes, I did implement both of them inside the ViewController.m (unless I needed to add the definitions in the .h file). I wonder if I need to create a new class for the ViewController?